# Angular Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant or a read-only property

Tags: angular, typescript

Im getting error Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant or a read-only property. When send data to api. Any one know how can i solve this ? Thanks

```
  onSubmit() {
  name = this.backUrl || 'admin';
  console.log(name);
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('avatar', this.form.get('avatar').value);
    formData.append('name', name);


    this.uploadService.uploadFile(formData).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.uploadResponse = res;
          console.log(res);
      },
      (err) => {  
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: which line are you getting error. I also see that the `name` in second line is not a `var` or `let`

Comment: can you first delete the key `name` and try to initialize it again like this 
`formData.delete('name');
 formData.append('name', name);
`

Comment: Thanks @sachin Gupta adding let with name solve the error thanks again

Comment: Posted as answer, accept if it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `name` as a `let` or `var` to assign values to it.